# List Index out of Bounds: -1

Tags: apex

I know List Index out of Bounds: positive num but I am getting 
`List Index out of Bounds:  -1` error. What does this mean ?

```
if(pnlNewYearsd.size() > 0) {
    startYear = pnlNewYearsd.get(0);
} else{
    if(startYear == '') {
    // getting error in below line 
    startYear = **temp_hop_id_list[(temp_hop_id_list.size()/2)-1].Year__c;**
    } else {
    startYear = temp_hop_id_list[temp_hop_id_list.size()-1].Year__c;
    }                      
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful for us if you can post some code and highlight the line where you are getting the error.

Comment: @manjit_singh updated post

Comment: If your list size is 1 your code will blow up at the time of (size()/2) - 1. This will  result in a negative value and is more than likely why you are receiving index out of bounds.

Comment: Your `temp_hop_id_list` list seems to have a size of 0. Add a condition to manage this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into this issue based on the size of your `temp_hop_id_list`. At the point of performing the division on list size your list size appears to be `<= 1`.

Here is some logic I have created to illustrate how you would recieve a `List Index Out Of Bounds: -1` error.

```
List<Contact> emptyCons = new List<Contact>();

if(emptyCons.size() > 0) {
    system.debug('Woohoo');
} else {
    system.debug('Below is a List Index Out Of Bounds -1 error.');
    system.debug((cons.size()/2)-1);
}
```

**Changes needed to your logic:**

```
if(pnlNewYearsd.size() > 0) {
    startYear = pnlNewYearsd.get(0);
} else {
    if (temp_hop_id_list.size() >= 2) {
        startYear = startYear == '' ? temp_hop_id_list[(temp_hop_id_list.size()/2)-1].Year__c : temp_hop_id_list[temp_hop_id_list.size()-1].Year__c;
    } else {
        // Exception Handling
    }                    
}
```

Here you are making sure your list size is greater or equal than 2 to allow the division only ever end with a result of 0 or more.

I have also cleaned up all the if/else statements and used a [ternary operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says: you are trying to index the array at element -1. Caused by the expression between [ and ], meaning that temp_hop_id_list.size()/2 has a value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think temp_hop_id_list.size() is of size 0 or 1 . You can add condition to handle this error.

```
if(think temp_hop_id_list.size()>=2) {
    startYear = temp_hop_id_list[(temp_hop_id_list.size()/2)-1].Year__c;
    } else {
    startYear = temp_hop_id_list[temp_hop_id_list.size()-1].Year__c;
    }  
}
```